# use of unresolved identifier in swift with ubuntu 14.04

Tags: swift, ubuntu-14.04

honestly i am a noob in swift, but i have a project to do with this language, so, here is the code:

```
import Foundation

//let dirs = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true) as? [String];
//let dir = dirs![0];
var dir = "/home/guillermo/Escritorio/";
var file = "tokens";
var path = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(file);
if let archivoTokens = try? NSString(contentsOfFile: path as String, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding){
    print(archivoTokens)
  }
var lineasArchivoTokens:[String] = archivoTokens!.componentsSeparatedByString("\n");

var TOKENS:[String] = [String]();

var count = lineasArchivoTokens.count;
for index in 0..<count{
    var tmpList:[String] = (lineasArchivoTokens[index]).componentsSeparatedByString(" ");
}
```

and this is the error:

```
error: use of unresolved identifier 'archivoTokens'
var lineasArchivoTokens = archivoTokens!.componentsSeparatedByString("\n");
```

Comment: You can only use archivedTokens inside the if let statement's { }. You can replace it with a guard or put the code that needs to access it within it's scope.

Comment: ok, I just modify the code to avoid the condition, and now I get this message:                                                                                                          error: cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'String' var lineasArchivoTokens:[String] = archivoTokens!.componentsSeparatedByString("\n");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @thefredelement said, you cannot use `archivoTokens` outside the `if let archivoTokens = ... { ... }` block.

You can reflow your code like this:

```
if let archivoTokens = try? NSString(contentsOfFile: path as String, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding){
    // note that archivoTokens here is not an Optional because it is garenteed not to be nil
    // so the ! suffix is not needed
    print(archivoTokens)
    var lineasArchivoTokens:[String] = archivoTokens.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
}
```

Or, in a more natural way, use `guard`:

```
guard let archivoTokens = try? NSString(contentsOfFile: path as String, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) else {
    // guard statement requires exit when condition not satisfied
    // you can also use `return` if it's inside a function
    fatalError("failed to read archivoTokens from file")
}

// now archivoTokens is a normal non-nil NSString

var lineasArchivoTokens:[String] = archivoTokens.componentsSeparatedByString("\n");

var TOKENS:[String] = [String]();

var count = lineasArchivoTokens.count;
for index in 0..<count{
    var tmpList:[String] = (lineasArchivoTokens[index]).componentsSeparatedByString(" ");
}
```